# Angular: Accessing DOM by instantiating component

Tags: angular

I am working on an angular application, where data is presented graphically. To visualise these data, angular components were created and are accessible by navigating to the respective pages.

There is requirement to export that data to PDF and PPT even if we are not in that page.

Is there a way to instantiate an Angular Component and have access to the respective HTML DOM (generated template code)? Having that html it then would be passed to the PPT or PDF generator.

I am trying to find if someone was doing something similar out there, but I haven't found anything on the web.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: In the past when this had to happen we just opened a new window outside of screen view to render the relevant components with a quick css transform attached like `transform: translateX(-5000px)` to then grab the output for the image to be used in pdf/ppt/whatever and the closed the window immediately after contentchecked. Leaving as a comment simply because it may not be the best way, but it worked...

Comment: What about something around testing libraries that check the generating image of a component vs the correct image?